# want compare Java.time.LocalDate & java.time.LocalTime in compareTo()

Tags: java, compareto, java-time

I have a `Meeting` class that implements `Comparable<Meeting>`. Overridden `compareTo` method will compare `meetingDate` of two `Meeting` objects first and in case they are equal it will compare their `meetingTime`. I want to put all my `Meeting` objects in a `ProirtiyQueue<Meeting>` so I can retrieve the upcoming meetings as per their `meetingDate` and `meetingTime`. Data type used are java.time.LocalDate and java.time.LocalTime respectively. How can I compare `meetingDate` and `meetingTime` in my `compareTo(Meeting o)` method.

```
 public class Meeting implements Comparable<Meeting> {

private String title;
private String desciption;
private LocalDate meetingDate;
private LocalTime meetingTime;

public Meeting(String title, String description, LocalDate meetingDate, LocalTime meetingTime) {
    this.title = title;
    this.desciption = description;
    this.meetingDate = meetingDate;
    this.meetingTime = meetingTime;

}

public String getTittle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTittle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return desciption;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.desciption = description;
}

public LocalDate getMeetingDate() {
    return meetingDate;
}
public void setMeetingDate(LocalDate meetingDate) {
    this.meetingDate = meetingDate;
}

public LocalTime getMeetingTime() {
    return meetingTime;
}

public void setMeetingTime(LocalTime meetingTime) {
    this.meetingTime = meetingTime;
}

public int compareTo(Meeting o) {
    // comparison
}


}
```

Comment: Well normally you'd compare the dates first, and then if they're the same, compare the times. (If they're not, just return that result.) Basically this a matter of comparing by two properties, which happen to be the date and then the time... have you had any particular difficulty implementing it?

Comment: BTW you've got a typo in setTittle/getTittle.

Answer (score 2):

You can delegate the implementation of `compareTo` to a `Comparator` which can chain comparisons of multiple properties of the given Meeting:

```
public class Meeting {
    ...

    private static final Comparator<Meeting> comparator =
        Comparator.comparing(Meeting::getMeetingDate)
            .thenComparing(Meeting::getMeetingTime);

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Meeting that) {
        comparator.compare(this, that);
    }
```

Comment: Java 8 only, but neat trick.  I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: That's not a problem, LocalDate and LocalTime are already Java 8 only classes.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation,

**Date.compareTo()**

> Return : an int < 0 if this Date is less than the specified Date, 0 if they are equal, and an int > 0 if this Date is greater.

**Time.before()**

> true if this time is less than the given time

Then you need something like :

```
public int compareTo(Meeting o) {
    if (o == null)
      return (0);
    if (o.meetingDate.compareTo(meetingDate) == 0)
      return (o.meetingTime.before(meetingTime));
    else
      return (o.meetingDate.compareTo(meetingDate));
}
```

This function will return : 
"An int < 0" if o is before the currentMeeting object.
"An int > 0" if o is after the currentMeeting object.

Comment: Since we are overriding `compareTo()` shouldn't the return type be `int`.